# Question on insulators

Tags: electrostatics, insulators

Imagine a **grounded neutral insulating** sphere, if we bring an electrically **charged object** close to the sphere (without touching) and then cut off the grounding, can the sphere be electrically charged?

*(And if yes, would it be because of the high voltage or what?)*

Comment: Is the sphere grounded (conductively connected to ground), or insulated from the ground?

Comment: it's conductively connected to the ground

Answer (score 1):

The way you formulated the problem, the default answer is no. Since the sphere is insulating no charges can move either in or out of the sphere.

The only ambiguity might come from the piece of conducting wire that was used to connect the sphere to the ground. As a grounding wire it was completely useless as on an absolutely insulating body it only makes sure that the exact point where the wire was attached had zero potential. But the dangling cut piece of the wire has some capacitance and therefore can hold some charge which can be regarded as a part of the insulating sphere. The exact amount of (tiny) charge left on it depends very strongly on such details and the relative positioning between the sphere, wire and the external charge. But in any regard this charge is nothing but a parasitic artifact and is completely irrelevant for you problem. So the answer is: No, there will be no charge induced on the insulating sphere by the described procedure.